# java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to web scrape some data so that I can use it in my application.

The site I am trying to get data off is yahoo but I am getting a FileNotFoundException when it's trying to stream the data in.

I have also set the IP address and port explicitly.

Would be really thankful if someone can tell me where I am going wrong.

I have posted the sample code as well.

```
parentUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com";
pageUrl = new URL(parentUrl);
System.out.println(parentUrl);

try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pageUrl.openStream()));
} catch(Exception ex2) {
    ex2.printStackTrace();
}

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    out.write(inputLine);
    in.close();
}

out.close();
```

Comment: You need to show the code where you construct `out`. That'll be where the problem is.

Comment: Also note that you are calling `in.close()` inside your read loop. You'll never be able to read more than one line with this.

Comment: @CameronSkinner is right.. you just need to remove `in.close()` from your `while` loop.

Comment: @CameronSkinner - i removed that statement and pushed it outside the loop , its still giving me the same exception.
its creating a file test.html in the desired location but with no data in it.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the actual exception stacktrace

Comment: Add [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to help others to debug your code. In current version a number of questions emerges.

Comment: The `in.close()` isn't the problem that you're asking about. It was certainly a problem, but you need to show us what `out` is to diagnose the `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the initialization of `out`. You haven't shown us that code, but it will be something like:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("non/existent/path/somefilename");
```

It's probably due to you using a *relative* path, so to help you debug it, I recommend you change it to:

```
File file = new File("non/existent/path/somefilename");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()); // start with this simple debugging
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

My guess is that the path of the file is not where you think it is.